# No response on clicking on a folder

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner and I want to create a simple file browser but in my project when I try to click on any folder or file there is no response, how to fix this???

```
private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    ListDir(root);
}

void ListDir(File f) {
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    fileList.clear();
    for (File file : files) {
        fileList.add(file.getPath());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
    setListAdapter(directoryList);
}
```

Comment: Which part of the code you posted is supposed to detect and handle mouse clicks?

Comment: You need to call `setOnItemClickListener` form the ListView object, and define the action there.

Comment: Thanks for the help...!!!